# does the MKMapview.userLocation update when running background?

Tags: background, mkmapview, userlocation

I have set the "Required background modes" key to "App registers for location updates".
this allows  tracking the user’s location in the background. but when i get gps information from the mkmapview.userlocation background ,i found that the gps information is the same as when it is running foreground last time. 
this means the mkmapview.userlocation doesn't update when running background. Is that right? 
is there any idea to get user location information from the mkmapview.userloction when running background?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the MKMapview.userLocation isn't updating the location info when it is running background. so i have to use the cllocation to get location info background